# See inferred type of a variable in typescript?

Tags: filetype-typescript

Vim is my main editor but for typescript it's hard to see what the inferred type of a variable is. Whether it is a complex type or just a simple one, it'd be great to see the typescript inferred type

Asked here but no response
https://github.com/Quramy/tsuquyomi/issues/297

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use coc.nvim then you can look at their FAQ...it actually doesn't suggest the CursorHold+doHover but this is what I wanted

I can now click on a variable and it pops up a float window

```
" This makes the time before it updates your hover faster, other
set updatetime=300

" This makes it so that you can click a variable and a float window pops up
autocmd CursorHold * silent call CocActionAsync('doHover')
```

Output from my :CocInfo

```
vim version: NVIM v0.5.0-dev+1028-g702208daa
node version: v15.2.1
coc.nvim version: 0.0.80-79b07c7867
coc.nvim directory: /home/cdiesh/.local/share/nvim/plugged/coc.nvim
term: screen-256color
platform: linux
```

Look at the FAQ from coc.nvim for more tips but this minimal set of additions was enough for me

[image]

Comment: Note that after some time, I accepted the recommendation from the coc.nvim FAQ and now have their config to press shift+k (e.g. capital K) to produce a type definition instead of cursor hold + doHover

Comment: Specific line:

`nnoremap <silent> K :call <SID>show_documentation()<CR>`

Answer (score 1):

If you use LunarVim, press the following keys to peek type definition: <kbd>space</kbd> (`<Leader>`) -> <kbd>l</kbd> (lower-case `L`, LSP) -> <kbd>p</kbd> (Peek) -> <kbd>t</kbd> (Type Definition).